# Increasing step size in scipy.integrate.ode

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am using scipy.integrate.ode to solve a problem. I set `t0=0`,and `t1=100`. But when I run the code, I find the step size of t is too small and it costs too much time. Here is a part of my code:

```
t0 = 0
t1 = 1
ode45 = ode(func)
ode45.set_integrator('vode', method='bdf', order=15, nsteps=1)
ode45.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
while ode45.successful() and ode45.t < t1:
    ode45.integrate(t1, step=True)
    lorenzT.append(ode45.t)
    lorenzY.append(ode45.y)
```

Here is the result when I print t in the loop:

```
...
t=0.0180750420686
t=0.0184795480338
t=0.0185806745251
t=0.0186818010164
t=0.018866421428
t=0.0192500222631
t=0.0196336230983
t=0.0200172239334
t=0.0204008247685
t=0.0207844256037
t=0.0211680264388
t=0.0214862880003
t=0.0218045495617
t=0.0221228111232
t=0.0226012818558
t=0.0230797525885
t=0.0231993702716
t=0.0233189879548
t=0.023438605638
t=0.0237217832039
t=0.0240049607698
t=0.0242881383358
t=0.0244043822203
t=0.0245206261048
t=0.0248245961619
t=0.0253513596254
...
```

I can't know at what time t reaches 100. I would like to get a larger step size in t.

Comment: Can you post the code of your function? People here like a [mcve], so they can easily run your code and reproduce your problem.